# Why does the use of '_' wildcard in SQL not display any results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

For some reason, this executes and shows the Phone column, but it does not display and rows of data. I checked the numbers on the phone search with the data in the column, and I did not make any typos. Am I using the wild card in an incorrect format?

```
SELECT Phone
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Phone LIKE '360-287-_'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore matches any *single* character, so the pattern `360-287-_` would match, for example, the number `360-287-1`, but not `360-287-12`, or any similar longer number.

Perhaps you intended to use the pattern `360-287-%`, which would match any number *starting* with `360-287-`.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for four more digits, not one:

```
SELECT Phone
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Phone LIKE '360-287-____'
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you want `%`, not `_`.  The latter only matches a single character:

```
SELECT Phone
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Phone LIKE '360-287-%'
```